# How can I change TalkBack speech when a list item gets focus?

Tags: android, accessibility

I've used the Google UserRowView class as a template of how to override dispatchAccessibilityEvent() in order to have TalkBack speak a custom message:

```
public class UserRowView extends LinearLayout {
                .
                .
  public void setText(String text) 
      _message = text;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessEvent) {
      Context ctx = this.getContext();
      accessEvent.setClassName(getClass().getName());
      accessEvent.setPackageName(ctx.getPackageName());
      accessEvent.getText().clear();
      accessEvent.getText().add(_message);
      return true;
  }
```

The list item layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="@color/all_white">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/member_active" />
<com.topiatechnology.skoot.android.util.UserRowView
    android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_user_row_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_name_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_size_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_date_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
        android:layout_width="200dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/catalog_entry_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />
</com.topiatechnology.skoot.android.util.UserRowView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set the text in my getView() method in the ListView's adapter.

The problem is that TalkBack does not change the text it speaks when a list item is focused on.

For the layout above, the text of the three TextViews is spoken while I want the text I set to be spoken.  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [View.setContentDescription()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to set a content description on the layout containing the views that you don't want read aloud. TalkBack will read the content description and ignore the text of the child views.

```
. . .

public void setText(String text) 
    _message = text;
    setContentDescription(_message);
}
```

In general, setting the AccessibilityEvent text to control feedback from focus and selection is no longer recommended.

Comment: I had been setting the content description before I tried overriding dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent but forgot to invalidate the view.  I removed the override at your suggestion.  Once I invalidated the view after calling setContentDescription, the description was read aloud.  One note is that I noticed the content descriptions of the views in the layout are still being spoken.

Comment: Could you check what version of TalkBack you're running? Settings > Apps > All > TalkBack

Comment: I'm running version 3.1.1_r68.

Comment: From the code sample, it looks like everything is set up correctly. This may be fixed in the current beta release, which is available at https://eyes-free.googlecode.com/files/com.google.android.marvin.talkback-v3.1.4-beta5.apk

Let me know if it's still an issue, and we can get it fixed before the next Play Store release.

Comment: When I set the content description on a LinearLayout that contains some TextViews, the content description of the LinearLayout and the text of each Textview are read aloud.  I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or not.